# How to let Asynctask update UI in different ways

Tags: android, design-patterns

This is a problem that I keep running into often with using Asyntask. The way to contact the UI thread is to call publishProgress() & this method accepts an array of **only one TYPE** of parameter.

A thread running in the background doing complicated computations might need to update the UI at different points using ***different types*** of object.

Let me illustrate with an example:

```
...do some processing...
// Send UI thread the integer values of the width & height of the image 
...do some more processing...
// Send UI thread a String with custom message.
...do some more processing...
// Send UI thread an instance of MyObject so it can extract & display certain values 
...do some cleanup job & finish...
```

However, onProgressUpdate() accepts an array of only one type.

So do I make that an all encompassing *Object* type? How do I know how to downcast it since this method can be called from line 1, 2 or 3 so which time is it?

Surely there must be a good way to achieve this?

EDIT: What I'd really love to see, if it were possible in Android, would be some way of defining *publishProgress1(user-defined args1)*, *publishProgress2(user-defined args2)*, *publishProgress3(user-defined args3)* ...

Comment: I believe that you are asking for a construct similar to a VARIANT http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type

Comment: @JAL: Thanks for sharing the interesting link. Variant_type with its run-time type determination remind me very much of Object type in Java with run-time downcasting. What I'd really love to see, if it were possible in Android, would be some way of defining *publishProgress1(user-defined args1)*, *publishProgress2(user-defined args2)*, *publishProgress3(user-defined args3)* ...

Comment: @OceanBlue VisualBasisVARIANT is an old solution, but I would rather see a more type safe solution possibly you could tackle launching three sequential threads using messages and a single handler that switches on message.what. So launch thread returns message(0) with return type A, trap message in handler, launch thread with message(1) return type B, trap and launch thread with message(2) etc.

Comment: @JAL:The thing with breaking the task into smaller tasks/different threads is that if your work needs to be done **serially**, the logic will break down. Unless... you get into the whole thread locking, wait/notify business, which I'd rather avoid, what with the potential deadlocks & stuff.

Comment: @OceanBlue I think you can do this _sequentially_ using messages as I outlined. You only launch the next thread when the first thread has returned. This may not work if the data cannot be passed by messaging. No need for thread locking, wait or notify using message passing concurrency which is quite different from shared memory concurrency. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_computing

Comment: @OceanBlue It just occurred to me. You can just use a single thread and send three separate messages with what 0, what 1 and what 2. Each message can contain a different type using msg.setData(bundle).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your 3rd case...

> // Send UI thread an instance of MyObject

...there's an argument to say you would do this in onPostExecute() although that depends on what you meant from your illustration.

You could easily do as you suggest in passing an all encompassing object. The object could have various fields (integer, string, object) plus an 'action' to take describing which of those fields are valid and need to be processed.

You could simply pass an int enum such as `PROCESS_INT_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT`, `PROCESS_STRING_MESSAGE`, `PROCESS_OBJECT` etc. There's nothing to stop you doing this...

```
private static class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, int, Void> {
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private String customMessage;
    private MyObject myObject;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

        width = 10;
        height = 10;
        publishProgress(PROCESS_INT_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT);
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(int... progress) {
        if (progress == PROCESS_INT_WIDTH_AND_HEIGHT)
            // Process width and height
    }
}
```

In other words, the onProgressUpdate() method simply responds to a 'command' and processes the relevant private fields accordingly.

Comment: The one danger here is that `publishProgress()` might get called more than once before `onProgressUpdate()` has its shot. If you modify your approach to have `publishProgress()` take an `Object`, with the 1st parameter being your `Integer` command ID, and the other parameters being the rest of the data, you would avoid this problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Valid point  - depending on the complexity of the tasks involved, it could cause problems. My preference would actually be the 'all encompassing' object the OP hinted at with the action/command to be performed being embedded (as you say). In a sense this emulates the way Intents can be used - the same data parameters can be supplied in different cases but the 'action' ultimately decides the outcome.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that might be the best way to go about it, under the limitations. Please see EDIT.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to stick with [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), another option is use a different class at different times, and test the type with instanceof.

However, this sounds like a relatively complex task, so I'd suggest looking at using [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) and posting it [Runnable]s[2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) from a regular [Thread](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html), or using [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

You might also want to read [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: +1 for the links. Those are great links & I've read them before. I think AsnycTask was basically created to avoid the complexity(& potential pitfalls) of Handlers & Threads, so I'd like to stick to it whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any other way of doing this. Create a base class with a getType method and then use this as your type for appropriate casting.

Answer (score 0):

Would a generic type work in this scenario? You could typecast the values as needed. Example `AsyncTask` prototype:

```
new AsyncTask<String, Object, List<?>>(){ 
...
```

I also recall reading that `AsyncTask` is most suited only for short tasks. Consider the other thread models for complex and long-running operations.

Comment: Services are not meant to be long running tasks but just a way to run something in background. For long running tasks, one should use thread even in a Service.

Comment: Not really long-running. Just a few seconds. But those can seem long to a user staring at a stationary screen too. Say along the way you wanted to do a few things... show a message, then some processing, update the integer values & so on. Hope my question makes sense!

Comment: @OceanBlue You may still consider breaking your task into smaller parts or using a lower-level model. `AsyncTask` does not seem perfect for all situations. Also consider playing around with generic types for your desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If the values you're returning have a corresponding state in the `AsyncTask` processing, you could create a private member inside the `AsyncTask` for each datum/type you need, then assign an integer to each state and in `onProgressUpdate(Integer...)` put a `switch(state)` that does the job based on the int state it gets from `publishProgress(state)`.

(this might not be the clearest answer I gave)